# Applying application css to React Portal (Opens new window) in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to instantiate my react application into a new window using React Portal, but the function I am using to copy the styles from the parent window into the new window doesn't run in IE/Edge. It slows the browser down badly and then crashes. It will try to work for about 3-4 minutes before crashing. So, I currently don't have any styles being imported to the new window in IE/Edge - Chrome & FireFox work perfectly fine. Does anyone know how to get my local css into the new window?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function copyStyles(sourceDoc, targetDoc) {
  Array.from(sourceDoc.styleSheets).forEach(styleSheet => {
    try {
      if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
        const newStyleEl = sourceDoc.createElement('style');

        Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).forEach(cssRule => {
          newStyleEl.appendChild(sourceDoc.createTextNode(cssRule.cssText));
        });

        targetDoc.head.appendChild(newStyleEl);
      } else {
        const newLinkEl = sourceDoc.createElement('link');

        newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
        newLinkEl.href = styleSheet.href;
        targetDoc.head.appendChild(newLinkEl);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // console.log(e);
    }
  });
}

export default class Portal extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    closeWindowPortal: PropTypes.func,
    browser: PropTypes.string,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    closeWindowPortal: () => null,
    browser: '',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.childWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1400, height=490');
    this.containerEl =
      this.props.browser === 'IE' || this.props.browser === 'Edge'
        ? this.childWindow.document.body.appendChild(
            this.childWindow.document.createElement('div')
          )
        : document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { browser } = this.props;
    if (browser !== 'IE' || browser !== 'Edge') {
      this.childWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
      // apply css to the new window by calling function at top of file
      copyStyles(document, this.childWindow.document);
    } else {
      this.childWindow.document.body.div.appendChild(this.containerEl);
    }
    this.childWindow.document.title = 'EarthCam Share';

    this.childWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      this.props.closeWindowPortal();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.childWindow.close();
    this.childWindow.removeEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      this.props.closeWindowPortal();
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl); //eslint-disable-line
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to attach the css to the div element that was created and then it worked

```
copyStyles(document, this.externalWindow.document);
//this part got css working in chrome and firefox
this.containerEl.className='class1 class2';
```

I had to abandon this route entirely since I couldn't get IE 11 to work with the react-portal code.